# Related Articles from same child category - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to add some related articles at the bottom of my wordpress posts.

All my posts are categorized in BOTH a parent and child category. I need to pull four RANDOM related posts from the same CHILD category as the main post (not the first four in the category) then display them at the bottom of the post, through `single.php`.

I'm a newbie to WP & the loop.... any ideas on how I do this?

Edited to include the code I'm using to display posts on category pages - the random related posts need to be in this same grid.

```
          <!-- START OF THE FLEX CONTAINER, THE UNORDERED LIST -->
    <ul class="grid-wrap">

        <!-- WP LOOP STARTS HERE -->
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <!-- LIST ITEM FOR EACH POST -->
            <li class="grid-item">

                <!-- FEATURED IMAGE FOR THE POST -->
                <p>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </p>

                <!-- POST TITLE -->
                <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- END OF THE LIST ITEM -->
            </li>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>></div>

    <!-- END OF THE FLEX CONTAINER -->
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you check this link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41272/how-to-show-related-posts-by-category ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code is already written for related post, you need to add the **random** order into it.

```
  $args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Please change it according to you code. If you have any issue please let me know about it.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I've used the answer that Jomal John linked above which successfully gives me related posts. But my category pages are organised in a flex grid system, and I can't get the related posts to display using the same grid system. I've posted the code for that grid above. No matter what I do they seem to end up in a list.

Then, where do I put that random code?

Thanks.

Comment: For that I need to see the code you are working in single.php. Can you please post that code for related post here.